# delete data from two tables at a time

Tags: laravel

I have an id using that I want to delete data from two tables. The two tables are 'taxrate' and 'tax'. In the taxrate model how to write.

```
public function deleteTaxrate($taxId){

}
```

How to write code in laravel for this?

Comment: You don't need to write the deletion code in your taxrate model, You can do it in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
public function deleteTaxrate($taxId){
   Taxrate::destroy($taxId);
   Tax::destroy($taxId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write code like this for laravel:

```
<?php

use App\Taxrate;
use App\Tax;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

public function deleteTaxrate($taxId)
{
    Taxrate::where('tax_id',$taxId)->delete();
    Tax::where('tax_id',$taxId)->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function deleteTaxrate($taxId)
{
    Taxrate::destroy($taxId);
    Tax::destroy($taxId);
}
```

and remember you should `use` the models of `taxrate` and `tax`, like this in first of your controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Taxrate;
use App\Tax;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function deleteTaxrate($taxId){
    Taxrate::find($taxId)->delete();
    Tax::find($taxId)->delete();
}
```

or

```
public function deleteTaxrate($taxId){
    Taxrate::where('tax_id',$taxId)->delete();
    Tax::where('tax_id',$taxId)->delete();
}
```